# One computer cant access shared files

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

We have about 80 computers that are domain joined.
All but 1 can access the `S:\testdata\test1.docx`

On one computer no matter which user account I log into on that computer with I can see the file, but when I right click and press `properties>security` it says that I don't have permission to view the permissions. I also cant copy the file.

If I login with the same user on another computer I can access the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the problematic workstation has the correct system time.
2. Rejoin the problematic workstation to the domain.

This problem could be a symptom of a broken trust relationship between the problematic workstation and the domain controller.

Comment: Both good suggestions, usually windows is pretty good about informing you of a broken trust relationship but both are a good diagnostic step.

Comment: I would just start there because you can rule them both out in the first five minutes and then focus on the really interesting possibilities!

Comment: I have done both and still doesnt work.